# Ideas for ratio estimation (X and Y from different surveys)?

Tags: ratio

We are trying to estimate the rate of event X per hour exposed to certain activities (e.g. commuting) by combining statistics from two multi-year cross-sectional surveys, one for the denominator and the other for the numerator. However we don’t really know how to do this and are reaching out for any ideas.

The first question is, is it possible to estimate MEAN(X/Y) and VAR(X/Y), where X indicates cases and Y indicates hours of exposure? The typical ways to estimate ratio (e.g. delta method) may not work here, because X and Y are from two different surveys. We noticed that an old thread in other site (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-01/msg00723.html) suggests theoretically it is possible to estimate MEAN( X /Y) even though X and Y are from different surveys. Would doing so be exceedingly complicated (e.g. re-weighting the X, re-weighting Y…etc)?

So we came up with plan B:  what about just estimate MEAN(X)/MEAN(Y), and hence VAR(MEAN(X)/MEAN(Y))?  Certainly, by doing so we are not trying to calculate the average of individual rates, but simply the ratio between the total events divided by total exposure hours, a commonly-used method in epidemiological studies in estimating risk at the population level.

Then main question is, under plan B how do we calculate VAR(MEAN(X)/MEAN(Y))? Also, is estimating MEAN(X)/MEAN(Y) as straightforward as we thought, i.e. just substitute MEAN(X) with the sample mean, and do the same thing for MEAN(Y)?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done without knowing the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. This is intuitive since, suppose $bX = Y$ (corr = 1), then the ratio is $b$ always. Assuming things are independent without rigorously showing it is simply not a good idea. That can't be done without a joint data collection effort. Ignoring this is almost certainly biased. of estimating such quantities. The $\delta$ method can be used to derive a variance estimator which incorporates the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ if that is somehow a *third* measure you get from other studies.